# Moving the mouse blocks WM_TIMER and WM_PAINT

Tags: winapi, mfc

In an application I'm working on, in some cases the application runs pretty slowly and in these cases I've discovered that my moving the mouse, timer/paint messages are not being handled. If I move the mouse in a slow circle, I can indefinitely prevent the window being re-painted!

I found that this is [expected behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#quequed_messages):

> With the exception of the WM_PAINT message, the WM_TIMER message, and
>   the WM_QUIT message, the system always posts messages at the end of a
>   message queue. This ensures that a window receives its input messages
>   in the proper first in, first out (FIFO) sequence. The WM_PAINT
>   message, the WM_TIMER message, and the WM_QUIT message, however, are
>   kept in the queue and are forwarded to the window procedure only when
>   the queue contains no other messages. In addition, multiple WM_PAINT
>   messages for the same window are combined into a single WM_PAINT
>   message, consolidating all invalid parts of the client area into a
>   single area. Combining WM_PAINT messages reduces the number of times a
>   window must redraw the contents of its client area.

However, what can I do about this? Sometimes in direct response to a mouse-move, I need to re-paint as quickly as possible.

I catch messages through a method like this on my CWnd-derived class:

`virtual LRESULT WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);`

Comment: If you need to repaint immediately, call `InvalidateRect` followed by `UpdateWindow`, or `RedrawWindow` with the `RDW_UPDATENOW` flag.

Comment: I wondered if when `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is received, I could poll the message queue like `while(msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)` and only process the last `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message, avoiding stacking of similar messages.

Comment: The simple solution is to make your handling of `WM_MOUSEMOVE` faster

Comment: That is _not_ a simple solution, sadly.

Comment: You can call `PeekMessage()` in a loop to retrieve any `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages in the queue. You might also find you get better results if you ignore the coordinates in `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and read the cursor position yourself with `GetCursorPos()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WM_PAINT` and `WM_TIMER`, as you read in the docs, are different from other messages.

The practical difference is that they are *lowest priority* messages. That is, they will not be processed if there are any other messages in the queue.

That said, you are moving the mouse, so a lot of messages are being posted, but the frequency of these messages is usually quite low (a few dozens a second) so your program should be mostly idle, But it is not, probably because some of these messages is taking much more time than expected and it is choking the queue. You just have to detect which one and why.

Some of the mouse-related messages, out of my mind:

- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_SETCURSOR`
- `WM_NCHITTEST`

And from a search in the web:

- `WM_MOUSEOVER`
- `WM_MOUSELEAVE`
- `WM_NCMOUSEOVER`
- `WM_NCMOUSELEAVE`

Anyway, if you want to repaint immediately, without waiting for a `WM_PAINT` you should call `UpdateWindow()`. This function forces an immediate processing of `WM_PAINT` (if there is anything invalidated, of course) and blocks until it finishes, bypassing the low priority issue of that message.

**UPDATE**: According to your situation from your comments I think that your best solution may be something along these lines:

1. In `WM_MOUSEMOVE` save the cursor position in a member variable and set a flag meaning that the mouse has moved.
2. Implement an `OnIdle()` handler that checks the mouse moved flag. If not moved, do nothing. If moved, then do the expensive calculation.
3. You may try it with or without calling `UpdateWindow()` from `OnIdle()` and see which one is better.

Yes, it will still feel choppy in slow computers, but since `OnIdle()` has even lower priority than `WM_TIMER` and `WM_PAINT`, these messages will not be relegated indefinitely. And more importantly, you will not be queuing multiple calls to the expensive function.

Comment: It's basically the mouse-move functionality - we detect what's under the mouse (and a 3rd-partly lib does the same). It's a map application and if it's a very busy part of the map, a slower PC just spends all its time doing this. There's no easy fix to speed this up sadly, we just need to stop it taking priority in all cases.

Comment: If you are spending so much time in WM_MOUSEMOVE that you're choking your message queue, you should consider a worker thread. Your GUI should not be doing such heavy lifting.

Comment: @John: Say that you get a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` once each 10ms but it takes 25ms to process it: you have a problem. If you fix it with `UpdateWindow()` then the updates will lag behind the mouse. If you do not do `UpdateWindow()` then the redraw will not happen until the mouse is stopped... A working thread and doing the job just at one of every few points is probably your best solution.

Comment: I think that level of redesigning is not feasible at the moment, especially as we feed the mouse-move events into a closed-source 3rd-party lib. It would be quite OK if any `WM_MOUSEMOVE` events received during the 25ms were simply discarded but I don't know if `CWnd::WindowProc()` can 'suck' messages from the queue? In plain Win32 for game programming, you'd quite often do this - each frame you'd pop messages until the queue was empty, and _then_ render. **Regardless if this is good practice, an answer which demonstrates it would be welcome**

Comment: @John: Please, see my updated answer too is if it fits your problem.

Comment: @rodrigo Your concerns about UpdateWindow() are incorrect. If the mouse moves every 10 ms but you take 25 ms to process the message then WM_MOUSEMOVE message will be delivered every 25 ms. WM_MOUSEMOVE messages aren't queued.

If calling UpdateWindow() causes mouse handling to take even longer (50 ms?) then the incoming rate of WM_MOUSEMOVE messages will drop to match. With UpdateWindow() the window will be repainted 20 times per second. Without it -- zero.

UpdateWindow() is the solution.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/01/55108.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution in almost all cases is that when you update your application state in response to WM_MOUSEMOVE in such a way that repainting is required you should call UpdateWindow(). That is it. You shouldn't use PeekMessage(), GetCursorPos, OnIdle(), etc.

If you call UpdateWindow() then a WM_PAINT message will be forced and your window will be updated, the user will see a reaction to their mouse movement, and your application will feel responsive. This is good. This is, in fact, ideal.

If you don't call UpdateWindow() then another mouse message may appear before a WM_PAINT message gets delivered. Most mice can deliver WM_MOUSEMOVE messages at 128/s, touch-screens seem to run at 200/s, and gaming mice are probably even faster. So, if the user is moving the mouse quickly then WM_PAINT messages may never get a chance to be delivered if not forced. This leaves you in a situation where you are processing 100+ WM_MOUSEMOVE messages per second, but never painting the window. This means you have an *internal* framerate of 100 fps, and an *visible* framerate of 0 fps. Broken.

So, once again, the answer is to call UpdateWindow() after an WM_MOUSEMOVE processing that requires painting. You internal framerate may be lower (since now you do more work per message) but your visible framerate will now match your internal framerate, and it is your visible framerate that matters.

The extra WM_MOUSEMOVE messages will be quietly discarded, as described at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/01/55108.aspx

I have made this fix to many applications and the results have always been spectacular. This one-line fix frequently makes applications seem 10x more responsive.

Comment: This doesn't work if you are doing something like ticking animation to change colour or similar on WM_TIMER.

Comment: Okay, let's say that you are ticking animation in WM_TIMER. Fine. Do that.
And then another WM_TIMER comes along, so you tick the animation again.
And so on.

Your program keeps updating the animation, but since the screen is never updated all of this update work is wasted.

Theoretical? Hardly. I have seen this issue happen in multiple commercial software programs. The fix is UpdateWindow. If this means that WM_TIMER only gets called, say, once a second, then increment the animation parameters appropriately.

Your comment fails to acknowledge this risk.

Comment: Not really.  It's just a fact that WM_MOUSEMOVE will block WM_TIMER, so you'll never get to UpdateWindow as you'll never check to see if your state has changed.  This happens to components in your process (on that message pump) that are unrelated to the window receiving mouse movement.  Working around this requires quite a bit of added complexity (an idle handler instead of WM_TIMER, perhaps, etc.).

Comment: That clarifies your concern. The WM_TIMER message is documented as being low priority, but the documentation doesn't seem to say anything about the priorities of other messages - a missed opportunity.
You could have a thread that just spins in a loop calling Sleep(whatever) and then sending the appropriate message. It's too bad it is all so complicated.